# ES6 with Node.JS and SSH

Tags: node.js, shell, ssh

I am using some ES6 features in my Node.JS application like the `let` keyword. The server works just fine on my local machine. After having deployed the code to a remote machine (which can be accessed online) I discovered some weird behaviour: If I start the server by gaining access to a remote shell and then execute gulp, it works flawlessly:

```
local> ssh user@myserver.com
remote> gulp
```

However, if I take a shortcut by adding the command to SSH, Node.JS suddenly complains about the ES6 features:

```
local> ssh user@myserver.com 'gulp'
...
[10:39:54] [nodemon] 1.8.1
[10:39:54] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[10:39:54] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[10:39:54] [nodemon] starting `node bin/www`

/home/user/server/routes/searchItem.js:62
            let myItem = items.filter(item =>
    [10:39:54] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
        ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: Can you run a `ssh user@myserver.com 'node -v'` to check which version of node he is trying to use?

Comment: Have you compared the results of running the following via ssh and logging in: `node --version`, `echo $NODE_PATH`, `which gulp`, `echo $PATH`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening here is that you have two different copies of node installed. One of them is in a standard location and the other is in some other location that is getting picked up due to your `$PATH` being changed in your shell's init/login/session script (e.g. `.bashrc`/`.profile`/`.bash_profile`).

When you just do `ssh user@myserver.com`, an interactive session is started. This means that any shell init/login/session scripts are executed. However, passing an explicit command uses a different ssh protocol-level mechanism which does not trigger those scripts to be run before executing the command (this is why you usually see motd and other information when using the first method and not when using an explicit command).